# How to auto generate Cucumber steps with Data table for WebdriverIO in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, cucumber, webdriver-io

can anyone please advice on how to auto generate Cucumber steps in Visual Studio Code, when using WebDriverIO?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using VSCode as IDE for a while now. Unfortunately, there was no plugin to get this feature in it. There was a npm package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-cucumber-steps) which seems to be not maintained anymore.

There is answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45429046/3879644) which might be of little help to you.

Comment: Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/3879644/raju